# PHP namespacing and spl_autoload_register

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload, spl-autoload-register

I had spl_autoload_register working fine but then I decided to add some namespacing to bring in PSR2 compliance and can't seem to get it working.

Directory strcuture:

```
-index.php
-classes/
  -Class1.class.php
  -Class2.class.php
  -Class3.class.php
```

Each class starts with:

```
namespace Foo;

Class ClassX {
```

Index.php:

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
});

$myObj = new Class1();

echo $myObj->doSomething();
```

This products an error `Fatal error: Class 'Class1' not found in /var/www/myApp/index.php on line X`

My first thought was that I need to use a namespace with my instantiation, so I changed `index.php` to:

```
$myObj = new Foo\Class1();
```

However, then I get 
`Warning: include(classes/Foo\Class1.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/myApp/index.php on line 6`

If I do manual includes everything works fine,`include 'classes/Class1.class.php';` and so on.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

So the problem was that the `$class` being returned to `spl_autoload_register` was the namespace\class name, *with* the backslash intact.  So when I instantiated a new object:

```
$myObj = new Foo\Class1();
```

The include path became `/var/www/myApp/classes/Foo\Class1.php`, the backslash breaking the path.

I implemented this to fix the backslash, and it now works, although I do not know why this is necessary.

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    include 'classes/' . str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.class.php';
});
```

Comment: Won't this give `Warning: include(classes/Foo/Class1.class.php):`?

Comment: I feel that there should be more elegant solution, not just manually changing the slash direction. Did you find any better way?

Comment: The reason why I'm not happy with this answer is because it is working fine on my Vagrant box without `str_replace`, but when I deploy it on BlueHost it is not working, demanding for other sort of slashes.

Comment: Ok, I give up, there is nothing better than this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use **DIR** constant before your path, like:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    include __DIR__.'/classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
});
```

It will ensure the relative path will always be the same.

You have to use the "correct" folder structure:

```
myproject/
-loader.php
-class/
-- Namespace1/
--- Class1.class.php
--- Class2.class.php

-- Namespace2/
--- Class3.class.php
```

Comment: While that is a good tip, it was sadly not the fix in this case.

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you want to take a look, I have a project that uses a similar structure: https://code.google.com/p/flat-framework/ . It is still at the very beginning but maybe it will help you somehow...