# Namespace not working with __autoload magic function in php

Tags: php, oop, namespaces, include, magic-function

I have created a class named `class_one` with namespace `MyClassOne` as below.

class_one.php

```
namespace MyClassOne;

class class_one
{
    function __construct()
    {
        echo 'I am from Class One Constructor';
    }
}
```

And I am trying to use it in `index.php` file as:

```
namespace MyClassOne;
require_once('class_one.php');
$one = new class_one();
```

It's working fine but when I am trying to include with `__autoload` magic function as:

```
namespace MyClassOne;
function __autoload($className)
{
    include_once("$className.php");
}

$one = new class_one();
```

it gives an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MyClassOne\class_one' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\autoload\index.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\autoload\index.php on line 9

Please help me where I am doing wrong in this code? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Depending on where you store you class files and their extension it can be as simple as `spl_autoload_extensions(".class"); spl_autoload_register();`. I prefer to store my class files outside of the web root and add the absolute path to the include path. Makes it dead simple to add and use new classes.

Comment: look at below link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22494980/php-namespacing-and-spl-autoload-register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22494980/php-namespacing-and-spl-autoload-register)

Comment: I have put my classes in `classes` folder and using outside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're putting a namespace declaration in your program code, which puts the `__autoload()` function inside that namespace, making it `\MyClassOne\__autoload()` instead of the desired `\__autoload()`, so PHP doesn't fire it when trying to load a class.

Generally, you only want namespace declarations in your class definition files:

```
namespace MyClassOne;
class class_one
{
}
```

Then use `use` in your program code:

```
use MyClassOne\class_one;
$one = new class_one();
```

Or use the full class name:

```
$one = new \MyClassOne\class_one();
```

See [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) for details on generally accepted autoloading procedure.

Comment: If I `use MyClassOne\class_one;` at the top then Am I need to include class file?

Comment: Now I am getting this error: -Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MyClassOne\class_one' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\autoload\index.php:13 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\autoload\index.php on line 13-

Comment: The `use` statement simply registers an alias for long class names. You need to either use `include <file>` or register an autoloader to actually get the source code loaded. Note that `spl_autoload_register()` is preferred over `__autoload()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    include 'classes/' . str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.class.php';
});
```

Comment: __autoload depracted you will use spl_autoload_register function

Comment: Thanks for reply. I used it now it gives error Warning: include(classes/MyClassOne/class_one.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\autoload\index.php on line 8

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'classes/MyClassOne/class_one.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\autoload\index.php on line 8

Comment: Yes I have put the class in `classes` folder .

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.